# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms

i'm trying to add a post after the authentification and getting the name of the doctor who posted the post and add it into the blog.
When i click on submit to add the post i get this error :

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

but when i check the database i found the post.

This is the controller postcontroller :

```
 public function add()
       {


        $blog= new blog;

        $blog-> title = request('title');
        $blog ->body = request('description');
        $blog->author_id=request('articlemed');
        $blog ->image = request('photo');
        $blog-> save();
        return view ('index') ; 


    }
```

and this is the form :

```
     <form action="{{ url('/add') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
     <label for="">Titre de l'article</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id=""  placeholder="Titre de l'article">
     <label for=""> Description de l'article</label> </br>
     <textarea name="description" id="" cols="63" rows="20"></textarea> 
     <label for="">Image pour l'article</label>
     <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control" id=""  placeholder="Titre de l'article">
     <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="articlemed" value="{{$med->ID}}" />
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Ajouter l'article </button>
     </form>
```

and this is the web.php :

```
Route::post('/add', 'postcontroller@add');
```

also this is the controller of the authentification :

```
  public function authentification (Request $request) 
    { 
        $this->validate($request, [

        'email' => 'required',
        'mdp'=> 'required'
    ]);

    $logmedecin=doc::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() ;
    $rdv=rendezvous::get(); 

    foreach ($logmedecin as $log ) 
    {
        if (( $log->Login== $request->input('email') ) && ( $log->Password== $request->input('mdp') ))
        {
            return view ('/bienvenu',['med'=>$log] ,['pat'=>$rdv] );
        }
    }
    return back()->withErrors([
        'message'=> 'Emails or password not correct!'
        ]) ; 
}
```

and the web.php of the authentification :

```
Route::post('/bienvenu','doctor@authentification')->name('aziz');
```

Comment: try to add a get route too like so `Route::get('/add', 'postcontroller@add');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was that i didn't use the relationship between post and user (one to many)
so i just add this one to my Post model :

```
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\doc');
    }
```

And i add this to the user model :

```
 public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\blog');
    }
```